# GB tourism visa for minor acccompanied by uncle & aunt

Tags: visas, uk

We are currently planning for a three-week holiday in England this summer. Because we are concerned that our son might be bored and because it might be interesting for our niece, we are thinking about taking our niece along.

Our niece is twelve years old. Me and my son are German citizens, so we do not need visas. My wife and our niece are long-term residents of Germany, but citizens of a non-Schengen/non-EU/non-OECD country (say ex-Soviet Central Asia).

We believe the visa for my wife should not be a big problem, but what about the visa for our niece, who would be travelling without her parents? Is it likely that she will get a visa or is it maybe so unlikely that we do not really need to bother?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Under 18 Standard Visitor Visa Page](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor/if-youre-under-18) states :

> #### Travelling with an adult
>
> You’ll need to show that your parent or guardian consents to your
> travel and accommodation arrangements. If you do not need a visa to
> travel, you’ll need to prove this at the border.
>
> If you do have to apply for a Standard Visitor visa, you’ll need to
> identify the adult travelling with you in your visa application.
>
> If the person you’re travelling with is not your parent, you’ll need
> to provide specific information about them in your application.
>
> You can identify up to 2 adults in your visa application. Their names
> will appear on your visa. The adult can apply for a visa at the same
> time, but you must each complete separate applications.
>
> If you arrive in the UK without the person named in your visa, you’ll
> need to show that your parent or guardian consents to your travel and
> accommodation arrangements.

Usually, you would prove consent with a (sometimes notarized) letter from **both** parents (except in specific cases when one or none of the parents hold the legal parental authority) stating approval along with the child's birth certificate, and a proof of relationship if the surname is different (for example from marriage name change) [UK Advice](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/224634/Children_travelling_to_the_UK_leaflet_A5_WEB_final.pdf) and should also be carried with you to present at the border if requested

UKVI has a [sample](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/348110/Letter_of_Consent_for_Minors_travelling_to_UK_Apr08.pdf) for that letter of consent

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was somewhat worried that our case would be exceptional, but it seems this is very normal business.

Comment: I do not know for Germany, but in Spain, it is quite normal --- the parents or the persons with the parental legal authority just have to go to a Police station and fill out a standard form for a kind of "temporary permission" for traveling with the minor. (I did that for my daughter and my sister a couple of times, but to be honest, it was for Schengen countries always, so I am not sure if that applies generically)

Answer (score 3):

A common reason for a UK visa to be denied is the perceived risk that the traveller might not leave the UK as planned. For this reason, a visa applicant is expected to demonstrate compelling reasons for them to return. The fact that your niece's parents are not travelling with her should thus count in her favour: The expectation would be that she'd rather return to Germany to live with her parents*, and not remain as an illegal immigrant in the UK.

If you are planning to pay for your niece's trip (and can afford this), then including her should not really make the visa situation any more complicated. Nicolas Formichella's answer covers the paperwork for having a minor travelling with you. If not, then the application also needs to convincingly cover how her part of the trip is being funded.

*I am assuming here that her parents also have permanent residency in Germany. If eg one of her parents is living in the UK, it would be far more complicated.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am well aware of this will-to-return stuff, but your mention of parents living in the UK is a good point, even if it does not apply in our case.